# Getting strange behavior when doing if(1>0) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison

I'm really at a loss here.  I have the following code:

```
function AddHeightToBottom(footerHeight)
{
    if ($('#myId1').length)
    {
        $('#myId1').height($('#myId1').height() + footerHeight);
    }
    console.log(('#myId2').length);
    if ($('#myId2').length > 0)
    {
        var dHeight = $('#myId1').height();
        var aHeight = $('.AF').height();
        $('#myId1').height(dHeight + aHeight);
        var newHeight = $('#myId1').height();
        alert(newHeight);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('why?!??????');
    }
}
```

$('#myId2').length is coming out to 1, as I'd expect.  However, when it does the comparison

```
if(1 > 0)
```

it's doing thing 2 EVERY time and I have no idea why.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's doing thing 2.  I would expect it to do thing 1

Comment: [It seems to work as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/r0zcoabg/). Can you create an example that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: I think you're reading it wrong.  It should be doing the if, not the else.  It is currently doing the else

Comment: Then `.length` is not greater than 0, when are you looking at what `.length` contains? Entering it on the console? when does this code run? Before the element exists?

Comment: Did you look at the JSFiddle I linked to? My original comment was wrong which is why I deleted it but I'm testing your code directly in that fiddle and it's doing what you would expect.

Comment: .length = 1.  I'm seeing it in firebug. @PatrickEvans

Comment: When though? Are you entering `$('#element').length` on the console or something?

Comment: @MikeC -- I saw your JSFiddle, and it's working how i think it should.  My example is not when I'm running it in the browser

Comment: You are using jquery, so make sure you are running it in document.ready:  $( document ).ready(function() {
if($('#element').length > 0)
{
    //do thing 1
}
else
{
    //do thing 2
}
});

Comment: @PatrickEvans  -- I have a breakpoint on the if statement.  I inspect the element.length at that time and it shows as 1

Comment: @SeanSmyth Like I said, you need to create an example that recreates this behavior. As you've described it, it will not fail.

Comment: @DanWeber -- No, it's not in document.ready, it's in some other function, but that's all the function is doing

Comment: The code shown works as expected, which means there is something about the rest of the code that isn't working as you expect it to do. You need to post enough of your code to enable us to help you, but the `if/else` is not, itself, broken or misbehaving.

Comment: @MikeC -- but it DOES fail.  That's why I'm confused

Comment: @SeanSmyth Look. You need to give us code that we can *verify* fails. The code you have posted is not enough to recreate the bug. We need enough to *recreate* the bug. If we cannot recreate the bug then we cannot confirm why it's failing for you.

Comment: Have you tried just using  `if ($('#element').length) {...}` there is no need for the larger than 0 condition

Comment: @deowk, Yes, I was doing that before and it wasn't working either.

Comment: I am pretty sure, your `$('#element').length` is not 1. Try `console.log($('#element').length)` just before if condition. Let us know what gets printed.

Comment: @Saad When I inspect, I get one.  When i do console.log I get 12.  So something is up here, but I would still expect it to do the expected behavior

Comment: @SeanSmyth You're getting 12? When searching by ID? Again, if you created a working example of the problem we'd be able to help you better.

Comment: @MikeC, Yeah, I'm getting 12, which is strange.  When inspect the HTML, there's only one element with that ID.  Due to the nature of my work I cannot really put more up here.

Comment: @SeanSmyth I understand not posting the whole thing but you need to distill it down to its simplest components and show it here. Also, it's literally impossible to get `12` when searching by ID. The browser does not allow you to have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: @SeanSmyth To help you, either you need to provide a working example or please do provide html and js code in the post.

Comment: @Saad  I've just updated the code to be EXACTLY what I have.  The only thing I've changed here are element names and variable names.

Comment: @SeanSmyth `console.log(('#myId2').length);`. You forgot to put the `$` in front. It should be `console.log($('#myId2').length);` That's why you're seeing 12.

Comment: @MikeC  whoops.  let me try again and I'll put what is logged

Comment: @MikeC Okay, it's logging as 0.  That's a start I can look into

Comment: @SeanSmyth ahh, at last, you got 0.

Comment: @Saad Damn you firebug!

Answer (score 5):

You are using jquery, so make sure you are running it in document.ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
   if($('#element').length > 0) { //do thing 1 } 
   else { //do thing 2 } 
});
```

If you are calling this in another function, then that function must appear in document.ready. A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready. * Quoted from link below.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```js
function AddHeightToBottom(footerHeight)
{
    if ($('#myId1').length){
        $('#myId1').height($('#myId1').height() + footerHeight);
    }
    console.log(('#myId2').length);
  
    if ($('#myId2').length > 0)
    {
        alert("See, it works...");
      
        var dHeight = $('#myId1').height();
        var aHeight = $('.AF').height();
        $('#myId1').height(dHeight + aHeight);
        var newHeight = $('#myId1').height();
        alert("New height: " + newHeight);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('why?!??????');
    }
}

$( document ).ready(function() { 
  var footerHeight = 25;
  AddHeightToBottom(footerHeight);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myId1">div with id of myId1</div>
<br>
<div id="myId2">div with id of myId2</div>
```

Comment: Edited response to show it working. Perhaps you forgot to load jQuery? Are you including it twice? It's something related to jQuery in my opinion.

Comment: Try document.getElementById("myId2").length if you want to confirm it's related to your jquery setup.

Answer (score 0):

The element I was trying to grab was being loaded in an iFrame, so document.ready() wasn't catching it.  I don't know why Firebug was telling me the length was 1 when it was actually 0.